# getopts: optional $OPT_ARG

Tags: getopts

I am looking to create a script that can run both -u and -u gtest_filter=

Currently I have

> while getopts u: opt  2> /dev/null; do
>
> case $opt in
>
> u) UNIT_TEST=1; UNIT_TEST_OPTION=$OPTARG ;;
>
> ?) usage >&2; exit 1 ;;
>
> esac
>
> done

But makes it mandatory to have an argument. How can I fix this so that -u also works.

Answer (score 0):

Use `u` instead of `u:` (remove the colon). Then check the next argument to see if it starts with a `-`

```sh
while getopts u opt 2> /dev/null; do
case $opt in
u)
    UNIT_TEST=1;
    # Test first character of next option
    if [ "$(echo "$2" | head -c 1)" != "-" ]; then
        UNIT_TEST_OPTION=$2
        shift # Move on to next option
    fi
    ;;
?) usage >&2; exit 1 ;;
esac
done
```